# To chop of the last string from a series of strings separated by "/"

Tags: c

I'm trying to store the last occurrence of the string. But the strrchr - gets the last occurrence of the character we are searching for.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
        char* str = "/angus/declan/";
        char* str1 = "dir1/";
        char* str2 = "/clington";
        char* lname,*lname1,*lname2;
        lname = strrchr(str,'/');
        lname1 = strrchr(str1,'/');
        lname2 = strrchr(str2,'/');
        printf("\n lname : %s lname1 : %s lname2 : %s \n",lname,lname1,lname2);
        return 0;
}
```

o/p :

```
lname : / lname1 : / lname2 : /clington
```

But I wanted to print the above as Declan,dir1,clington without "/" preceding or succeeding.

Comment: `strrchr` does not get the first occurrence of the character you are searching for, as you can see from `lname`.

Comment: Strrchr is doing the right thing. It may help to write out exactly what steps the program should take in each of the three cases, then turn that into code. Remember that you can "shorten" a string by assigning a '\0' character into any position in the string.

Comment: Yeah right.. updated the question correctly

Comment: How to insert the "/0" in "/" .. Is there a predefined function to overlay a string on top of the other.

Comment: In the code above, `lname = strrchr(str,'/'); *lname = '\0';` will overwrite the '/' and make the string end at the 'n'. You can then call `strrchr(str, '/')` again, and it will find the '/' after 's'.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: `str` is read-only (but that would be easy to fix: `char str[] = "/angus/declan";`).

Comment: @mafso Good point! I didn't notice that.

Comment: 1. Remove the `/` character from the end of the string pointed by `str`. 2. Remove the `/` character from the end of the string pointed by `str1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *last(const char *s, char sep){
    char *tmp = strdup(s);
    char *ret, *p = strrchr(tmp, sep);
    if(p){
        if(p[1]){
            ret = strdup(p+1);
        } else {
            *p = '\0';
            p = strrchr(tmp, sep);
            ret = strdup(p ? p+1 : tmp);
        }
        free(tmp);
        return ret;
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(){
    char *str = "/angus/declan/";
    char *str1 = "dir1/";
    char *str2 = "/clington";
    char* lname,*lname1,*lname2;
    lname  = last(str, '/');
    lname1 = last(str1, '/');
    lname2 = last(str2, '/');
    printf("\n lname : %s, lname1 : %s, lname2 : %s \n",lname,lname1,lname2);
    free(lname);free(lname1);free(lname2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi BLUEPIXY, Thanks. I haven't used strdup before , But from the man pages , I got to know that , strdup will return a pointer to a string, which is a duplicate of the string. I replaced strdup with p+1, and got seg fault. couldn't understand why the seg fault happened .

Comment: @Angus Replace with the following If you can not use `strdup`. `char *mystrdup(const char *s){ size_t len = strlen(s); char *ret = malloc(len + 1); if(ret){ return memcpy(ret, s, len + 1); } else return NULL; }`

Comment: Thanks again BLUEPIXY. The code works great. But I couldn't understand why cant we use like if(p[1]) ret = p+1.

Comment: @Angus 1) `free(tmp);` 2) `free(XXX)` at main.

Comment: 0)You need to create a copy because string literal can not be changed.

Comment: If ret hold tmp in the cond ret = strdup(p ? p+1 : tmp);
then ret will become dangling as we are freeing the temp before

Comment: Please help me understand. If we do ret = p+1. Then wont it point to the P+1th address

Comment: @Angus It cannot be released by `free` because it is part of memory(allocate by malloc family) that is reserved if it returns `p + 1`.

Comment: Thanks BLUEPIXY for explaining to my doubts. My doubts got cleared now.